# Chain modifications in relational database

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

Suppose that we have 3 related table in this manner in MySQL:

```
Table 1:         Table 2:          Table 3:
-------------    -------------     -------------
UserID      |    ProfileID   |     ArticleID   |
-------------    -------------     -------------
Username    |    UserID      |     UserID      |
-------------    -------------     -------------
Password    |    UserAvatar  |     Article     |
-------------    -------------     -------------
```

I need to delete every related records upon delete action on Table1. in other words, when user performs delete action on Table 1, related records from other related tables must be deleted automatically and not write tons of queries to achieve this or we have orphan records without its master record.

what should I do? 
what are the best practices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to perform a cascade delete. Here is what you have to do:

- Create `foreign keys` between the tables using UserID as the link
- The foreign key must be defined as `ON DELETE CASCADE`

And you are done.

**Update**

Not gonna give you *teh codez*. All you need to read is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html). Not gonna give you the fish, I'm teaching you how to catch your own fish.

Answer (score 1):

[Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)? Particularly the bit about ON UPDATE and ON DELETE.

If you want to keep your tables in a different engine tha innodb (which is the only one to support FK constraints), then wrap the DML access in procedures (with SECURITY DEFINER permissions and make sure you block the direct UPDATE/DELETE privileges for the user) or associate [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html)